# Add help documentation for new command loaded from external redis module within redis-cli

Tags: redis

Helps on commands within redis-cli are stored in `redis/src/help.h`.

I would like to provide my help for commands loaded via redis module (using loadmodule).  I could find relevant information from [Redis Modules: an introduction to the API](https://redis.io/topics/modules-intro)

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I did a check on [`redis/src/redis-cli.c`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/46a8cb2d187d830a97c9f9b4735e8ded806bf9c3/src/redis-cli.c#L478),  the help is created during compile time.  Currently there is no possibility to do that.

```
static void cliInitHelp(void) {
    int commandslen = sizeof(commandHelp)/sizeof(struct commandHelp);
    int groupslen = sizeof(commandGroups)/sizeof(char*);
    int i, len, pos = 0;
    helpEntry tmp;

    helpEntriesLen = len = commandslen+groupslen;
    helpEntries = zmalloc(sizeof(helpEntry)*len);

    for (i = 0; i < groupslen; i++) {
        tmp.argc = 1;
        tmp.argv = zmalloc(sizeof(sds));
        tmp.argv[0] = sdscatprintf(sdsempty(),"@%s",commandGroups[i]);
        tmp.full = tmp.argv[0];
        tmp.type = CLI_HELP_GROUP;
        tmp.org = NULL;
        helpEntries[pos++] = tmp;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < commandslen; i++) {
        tmp.argv = sdssplitargs(commandHelp[i].name,&tmp.argc);
        tmp.full = sdsnew(commandHelp[i].name);
        tmp.type = CLI_HELP_COMMAND;
        tmp.org = &commandHelp[i];
        helpEntries[pos++] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Redis module developers should not write their module command document in `redis/src/help/h`.  I would suggest the following:

1. Using a new Module API function, module developer register new command documentation (consisting of command syntax, summary, since, group) into a system hash.
2. `redis-cli` reads additional command documentation from the system hash, to populate the `helpEntries[]`.

Comment: You are correct - currently the API does not accommodate help needs. Please feel free to add that feature request to the project's repository (and best of luck with your module!)